# How to get the specific set of lines using unix

Tags: xml, unix, sed, grep

I have file containing xml transaction with 2 identifiers. but one of it has an identical id. I would like to ask how to extract the specific transaction. Are there any unix code that can get the extraction done. Below are the sample xml data:

```html
> ## Sample Transaction ##
START:RequestTrace::7/27/16 1:05 AM,<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:EAMWOSTATUSSet>
<p:WORKORDER action="Replace">
<p:CHANGEBY changed="1">MAXADMIN</p:CHANGEBY>
<p:SITEID>DU</p:SITEID>
<p:SOURCESYSID>CMS</p:SOURCESYSID>
<p:STATUS changed="1" maxvalue="APPR">WMTRL</p:STATUS>
<p:SUPERVISOR/>
<p:WONUM>F16070855833</p:WONUM>
</p:WORKORDER>
</p:EAMWOSTATUSSet>
</p:PublishEAMWOSTATUS>
::END:RequestTrace::
```

as you can see the two identifiers that i am referring to is WONUM and STATUS. Now the file contains thousands of these and to add on it, there are multiple data with the same WONUM. How can i get the specific WONUM and its unique status.

Thank you

Comment: Is this file an xml one or a text? Your example shows text, not a well formed xml.

Comment: its a text file containing xml data sir

Comment: and which tag you want to retrieve? <p:EAMWOSTATUSSet> ?

Comment: i would like to retrieve the whole message using the 2 identifiers (WONUM and STATUS)

Comment: it is better to provide expected output too.. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If this were valid XML, it would be easy to do with `xmlstarlet` or a similar program. However, it is not valid XML.